# Debugging a large memory leak in Instruments

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I'm currently investigating what appears to be a large memory leak in my application. Using Instruments' `Allocations` template and the mark generation feature I can see that after a UIViewController that I present is released there is a growth of 35MB!

I know the UIViewControlller is released because I have a log message that is printed when dealloc is called.

[image]

One thing that really stands out in the report is the "VM: Allocation" item which shows 16MB of memory allocated. I have no idea what this is, also it's just two allocations using 8MB each, this seem incredibly high.

My UIViewController has a MKMapView, UITableView, various labels and a slideshow of UIImages.

The UIViewController is using a nib file and IBOutlets which are mostly all weak references, there are a few strong IBOutlet references where I add and remove view's at runtime that I need to keep a strong reference to. Though it's my understanding that these will be released by ARC anyway, just to be double sure I nil them out in dealloc.

Viewing the stack trace for the two `VM: Allocations` shows only internal calls and nothing that is related to my code. It says the responsible libraries are `libGLVMPlugin.dylib` and `libCoreVMClient.dylib`.

Interestingly if I remove my MKMapView from the nib file the growth shows after the UIViewController is released goes down dramatically.

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on this or give me any pointers?

Comment: you have a leak in visual memory which is very strange. did you update your Xcode to 5.1.1 ?

Comment: Yep using Xcode 5.1.1.